# Activate Object Sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an embedded chart on a sheet and I am moving the chart to another sheet (which is created not by myself but by the code) with moveChartToObjectSheet method:

```js
 var charts = chartsSheet.getCharts()
    
 for (var i in charts) {
      
     var chart = charts[i];
      
     var objectSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().moveChartToObjectSheet(chart)
```

**But I can't activate this object sheet**. After moving the chart I loop all sheets and get object sheet's position in a loop, or I get sheet index and call .activate method but this sheet doesn't get active.

I even tried to activate by its name (though names can be different, if you deletу one, it adds next number to object sheet name) and no luck.

Is there a way to activate object sheet?

Comment: If you use `var myNewSheet ss.insertSheet('My New Sheet');` I believe you can then use `myNewSheet.moveChartToObjectSheet(chart)` to add the chart to the new sheet.  I have not tested this, though.

Comment: unfortunately this method is available only after Spreadsheet and not sheet.

Comment: Apologies, I did not include the line for setting ss: `var SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` another method would be to combine these but if you are doing something to read 2 different sheets in the same file you may find it faster to set ss as I did here.

Comment: I mean this methos is not available after "sheet" object. Only after spreadsheet (ss.moveChartToObjectSheet(chart)) but not sheet.moveChartToObjectSheet(chart)

Comment: Did a little digging.  You are moving the chart to a new [Sheet Type Object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet-type#OBJECT) if the chart is not in one already.  If it is, then it just returns the current object it is in.  Then at a sheet level it appears you will use [sheet.insertChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertChart(EmbeddedChart)) to put it in a new location.

Comment: Thank you!! I managed to re-insert my chart to another sheet too with new sizes. Great!